# ImportError in importing from sklearn: cannot import name check_build

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I am getting the following error while trying to import from sklearn:

```
>>> from sklearn import svm

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
   from sklearn import svm
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
   from . import check_build
ImportError: cannot import name check_build
```

I am using python 2.7, scipy-0.12.0b1 superpack, numpy-1.6.0 superpack, scikit-learn-0.11
I have a windows 7 machine

I have checked several answers for this issue but none of them gives a way out of this error.

Comment: Try updating scikit-learn to current version (0.13).

Comment: now I am getting the following error

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name __check_build instead of check_build

Comment: I did update to scikit 0.13

Comment: Does someone have a solution to my problem?

Comment: How did you install sklearn? Did you use a binary installer or a package installer (like easy_install or pip)?

Comment: I downloaded the exe file from sourceforge and just ran it and it got installed

Comment: I'm having multiple import errors. Looking n the code, I can see that method names are not accurate. I'm using W7 and anaconda. I also tried the github source and running the setup.py. Wow i hate Windoze so much right now...

Comment: reinstalling scikit-learn using pip solved my issue

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Worked for me after installing scipy.

Comment: Plus restarting the python shell. :)

Comment: Check if there is a file called "sklearn" in the same folder. Try running from a different folder. Solved it for me (my fault). Find file with <ls | grep -i "sklearn">

Comment: @Mannu Yes; Also for me on jupyter notebook, just restarting (shutting down and click-open again) that ipynb py-kernel worked without restarting all of the jupyter notebook.

Comment: `scipy.stats` also did not work also raised an error.  In my case, I had a file called `multiprocessing.py` in the same directory that somehow  conflicted with the kernel's socket connection.  Fixed by renaming the file `multiprocessing_.py` (leading underscore did not work).

Answer (score 51):

```
>>> from sklearn import preprocessing, metrics, cross_validation

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn import preprocessing, metrics, cross_validation
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from . import __check_build
ImportError: cannot import name __check_build
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> from sklearn import preprocessing, metrics, cross_validation
>>>
```

So, simply try to restart the shell!

Comment: Magic answers like this are not really helpful because they don't solve the problem. What if a restart doesn't fix it?

Comment: Just mentioning that this happened to me with scikit-learn 0.15.2 compiled against numpy 1.9 and python 2.7.

Comment: If you don't want to restart, `del sys.modules['sklearn.__check_build']; import sklearn` will also work

Answer (score 24):

My solution for Python 3.6.5 64-bit Windows 10:

1. `pip uninstall sklearn`
2. `pip uninstall scikit-learn`
3. `pip install sklearn`

No need to restart command-line but you can do this if you want.
It took me one day to fix this bug. Hope this help.

Comment: If you're essentially saying that the latest version of sklearn fixes the bug, it would be helpful to state which version numbers of sklearn you upgrade to. Thanks.

Comment: In Windows 10 I also had to enable long paths before executing these einstructions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778630/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2-no-such-file-or

Answer (score 9):

After installing `numpy` , `scipy` ,`sklearn`  still has error

Solution:

Setting Up System `Path` Variable for Python & the `PYTHONPATH` Environment Variable

System Variables: add `C:\Python34` into path
User Variables: add new: (name)`PYTHONPATH` (value)`C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages;`

Comment: go to C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\sklearn     Double click _init_.py and setup.py.

Answer (score 7):

Usually when I get these kinds of errors, opening the `__init__.py` file and poking around helps. Go to the directory `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn` and ensure that there's a sub-directory called `__check_build` as a first step. On my machine (with a working sklearn installation, Mac OSX, Python 2.7.3) I have `__init__.py`, `setup.py`, their associated `.pyc` files, and a binary `_check_build.so`.

Poking around the `__init__.py` in that directory, the next step I'd take is to go to `sklearn/__init__.py` and comment out the import statement---the check_build stuff just checks that things were compiled correctly, it doesn't appear to do anything but call a precompiled binary. This is, of course, at your own risk, and (to be sure) a work around. If your build failed you'll likely soon run into other, bigger problems.

Comment: I do not have _check_build.so in the folder , What can I do to get this for python 2.7

Comment: Did you try commenting out the line that tries to import it in `sklearn/__init__.py`?

Comment: For the moment, you can comment out the line that does the import, that should get you running. Can you then please open an issue in the issue tracker https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues looks like a bug.

Comment: FWIW Commenting out the `import` in `__init__.py` didn't fix the problem but did expose a different error - my scipy install had not succeeded. The error in the question was masking the real issue

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on Windows. Solved it by installing Numpy+MKL from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy (there it's recommended to install numpy+mkl before other packages that depend on it) as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34710032/2314737).

Answer (score 4):

I had problems importing SKLEARN after installing a new 64bit version of Python 3.4 from python.org.

Turns out that it was the SCIPY module that was broken, and alos failed when I tried to "import scipy".

Solution was to uninstall scipy and reinstall it with pip3:

```
C:\> pip uninstall scipy

[lots of reporting messages deleted]

Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.0.0

C:\Users\>pip3 install scipy

Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-1.0.0-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl (30.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 30.8MB 33kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in c:\users\johnmccurdy\appdata\loca
l\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from scipy)
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy-1.0.0

C:\Users>python
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
 on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
>>>
>>> import sklearn
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use Anaconda 2.7 64 bit, try

```
conda upgrade scikit-learn
```

and restart the python shell, that works for me.

Second edit when I faced the same problem and solved it:

```
conda upgrade scikit-learn
```

also works for me

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers worked for me. After some tinkering I unsinstalled sklearn:

```
pip uninstall sklearn
```

Then I removed sklearn folder from here: (adjust the path to your system and python version)

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages
```

And the installed it from wheel from this site: [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

The error was there probably because of a version conflict with sklearn installed somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

For me, 
I was upgrading the existing code into new setup by installing Anaconda from fresh with latest python version(3.7)
For this,

```
from sklearn import cross_validation, 
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
```

to

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV,cross_validate
```

Answer (score 2):

no need to uninstall & then re-install sklearn

try this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows:

I tried to delete sklearn from the shell: pip uninstall sklearn, and re install it but doesn't work ..

the solution:

```
1- open the cmd shell.
2- cd c:\pythonVERSION\scripts
3- pip uninstall sklearn
4- open in the explorer: C:\pythonVERSION\Lib\site-packages
5- look for the folders that contains sklearn and delete them ..
6- back to cmd: pip install sklearn
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem reinstalling anaconda solved the issue for me