# Python not installing sklearn

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, numpy, scikit-learn

I am working with ubuntu 14. I have downloaded the dpkg package for sklearn and unpacked it. i try to run `sudo python setup.py install`But it seems to be stuck in a loop

```
    compiling C++ sources
C compiler: c++ -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sklearn/utils/src
compile options: '-Isklearn/utils/src -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
c++: sklearn/utils/src/MurmurHash3.cpp
c++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sklearn/utils/murmurhash.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sklearn/utils/src/MurmurHash3.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sklearn/utils/murmurhash.so
building 'sklearn.utils.lgamma' extension
compiling C sources
C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC

compile options: '-Isklearn/utils/src -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: sklearn/utils/lgamma.c
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: sklearn/utils/src/gamma.c
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sklearn/utils/lgamma.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sklearn/utils/src/gamma.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -lm -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sklearn/utils/lgamma.so
building 'sklearn.utils.graph_shortest_path' extension
compiling C sources
C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC

compile options: '-I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: sklearn/utils/graph_shortest_path.c
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1761:0,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from sklearn/utils/graph_shortest_path.c:256:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ufuncobject.h:327:0,
                 from sklearn/utils/graph_shortest_path.c:257:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h:241:1: warning: ‘_import_umath’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 _import_umath(void)
 ^
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sklearn/utils/graph_shortest_path.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sklearn/utils/graph_shortest_path.so
building 'sklearn.utils.fast_dict' extension
compiling C++ sources
C compiler: c++ -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC

compile options: '-I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
c++: sklearn/utils/fast_dict.cpp
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1761:0,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from sklearn/utils/fast_dict.cpp:320:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
sklearn/utils/fast_dict.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* __pyx_pw_7sklearn_5utils_9fast_dict_1argmin(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
sklearn/utils/fast_dict.cpp:18786:44: warning: ‘__pyx_v_min_key’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
             return PyInt_FromLong((long)val);
                                            ^
sklearn/utils/fast_dict.cpp:3316:46: note: ‘__pyx_v_min_key’ was declared here
   __pyx_t_7sklearn_5utils_9fast_dict_ITYPE_t __pyx_v_min_key;
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ufuncobject.h:327:0,
                 from sklearn/utils/fast_dict.cpp:321:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h: At global scope:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h:241:1: warning: ‘int _import_umath()’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 _import_umath(void)
 ^
```

.. and continues on like that.

I have installed numpy, but I did it through ubuntu's software center. When I try to import sklearn within python I get

> from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "", line 1, in    File
>   "sklearn/**init**.py", line 37, in 
>       from . import **check_build   File "sklearn/__check_build/__init**.py", line 46, in 
>       raise_build_error(e)   File "sklearn/**check_build/__init**.py", line 41, in raise_build_error
>       %s""" % (e, local_dir, ''.join(dir_content).strip(), msg)) ImportError: No module named _check_build
>   **_______________________________________________________________________** Contents of sklearn/**check_build: setup.py
>
>   __init**.py               _check_build.pyx
>   _check_build.c            setup.pyc                 **init**.pyc
>   **_______________________________________________________________________** It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.
>
> If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
>   to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
>   `make` in the source directory.
>
> If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
>   Python version, your operating system and your platform.

I have no idea where sklearn/check_build is located.

My folder in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages is empty, but I can import numpy within python. Like I said, I used the ubuntu software center to install numpy, but not for sklearn which I regret doing now.

Comment: First, one should never (very rarely) do `sudo pip` as you may ruin your operating system and Python package installations this way. Instead, one should use `virtualenv` to locally install packages under non-root user: http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/

Comment: Can you get the end of the compilation output? What you pasted there are warnings and there is actual error there.

Comment: Also might be one of these errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274696/importerror-in-importing-from-sklearn-cannot-import-name-check-build

Comment: No, it seems that it just goes on in a loop, but I'll try it again.

Comment: I think it just spits out a lot of warning, so the output might be long.

Comment: Here's the output   Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sklearn/utils/fast_dict.o: Permission denied
error: Command "c++ -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c sklearn/utils/fast_dict.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sklearn/utils/fast_dict.o" failed with exit status 1

Comment: that would because i didnt use sudo. should I just use virtualenv instead?

Comment: you cannot install to the system python without using sudo

Comment: Yes, it is trying to create files under root user. I suggest you might want to take clean start with virtualenv's `--no-site-packages` option.

Comment: .... or just go down with `apt-get` route.

Comment: why did you not use pip to install scikit-learn?

Comment: I did. It went into the same loop. But it wasn't a loop at all. It does eventually finish, but python still can not import sklearn.

Comment: what versions of `numpy` and `scipy` have you installed?

Comment: not sure how to check, but probably the newest ones since I installed them through ubuntu's software center.

Comment: Oh dear, I ran whereis python. It appears I have many versions of python installed

Comment: /usr/bin/python3.4m /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python2.7-dbg /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python2.7-dbg-config /usr/bin/python /etc/python2.7 /etc/python3.4 /etc/python /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.4 /usr/bin/X11/python3.4m /usr/bin/X11/python2.7-config /usr/bin/X11/python2.7-dbg /usr/bin/X11/python2.7 /usr/bin/X11/python3.4 /usr/bin/X11/python2.7-dbg-config /usr/bin/X11/python /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.4 /usr/include/python2.7_d /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

Comment: you should run `which -a python` to find your installs. you only actually have two installs

Comment: okay python is located at /usr/bin/python.But I got my sklearn to import after I logout and logged back in. But the library files are located in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn

Comment: that is because of how you installed it

Comment: Okay thanks guys. I see I have newbified my python in ubuntu, but everything runs now. When I get time, I'll try uninstalling everything and reinstalling everything through virtualenv  thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3335911 no worries, I would leave your install as is., if it's not broke don't fix it ;)

Comment: A suggestion to drain the swamp rather than kill all the mosquitoes - pick a python distribution such as Anaconda or Enthought or whatever you like and just install that. The software center never seems to have the most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing sklearn and all dependencies with Anaconda package: https://www.continuum.io/downloads#_unix

It will be installed together with numpy and other packages, full list is available here: http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs

Answer (score 0):

If you want your package manager to handle everything, that usually works although you won't necessarily be on the most recent version

Otherwise do something along the lines of

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc g++ python-dev python3-dev python-scipy python3-scipy
```

and try to install/compile again. compiling python extension modules relies on having a working compilation environment, plus the extended or development headers for python. I'm not sure if those dependencies are 100% exactly right for Ubuntu b/c I've been using more openSUSE lately, but apt-cache search will turn you up the correct naming if I've made a typo

Answer (score 0):

One of new ways to handle issues due to environment is to handle it using docker images. This allows any developer to recreate the environment in any server within a single minute. You can pull the image from [here](https://hub.docker.com/u/acusensehub/).

This can also be performed very easily using the datmo CLI tool. We faced these problems ourselves and decided to build it.

Edit: You could install as follows,

```
apt-get update; \
apt-get install -y python python-pip \
                    python-numpy \
                    python-scipy \
                    build-essential \
                    python-dev \
                    python-setuptools \
                    libatlas-dev \
                    libatlas3gf-base

update-alternatives --set libblas.so.3 /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3; update-alternatives --set liblapack.so.3 /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3

pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Disclaimer: I work at [Datmo](https://datmo.io/)

Comment: It's not particularly clear how this answers OP's question. I'm sure a docker image could conceivably solve this problem, but as it stands all you've done is link to a place where some docker images exist. Why would docker fix the problem? How could I set an image up? What actually caused this problem in the first place?

Comment: @ymbirtt I have also added the segment of code from Dockerfile which let's one install sklearn. Hope that helps!