# ImportError: cannot import name __check_build while importing TfidfVectorizer from sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I am using Python 2.7.10 and have installed scikit-0.15.2 using pip and i already have "numpy-1.1.10" and "scipy-0.16.0" installed and it works fine but when i try to import TfidfVectorizer from sklearn to construct a term document matrix with tf-idf values

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
```

i get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import __check_build
ImportError: cannot import name __check_build
```

I have already gone through the earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274696/importerror-in-importing-from-sklearn-cannot-import-name-check-build) and tried the solutions but it didn't work.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274696/importerror-in-importing-from-sklearn-cannot-import-name-check-build

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have already gone through that post and worked on the solutions mentioned, but still i keep getting the same error.

Comment: Can you please verify that `import scipy` works from your script?

Comment: I havent used scipy in my scripts just sklearn

Comment: Right, but verifying that `import scipy` works will verify that you have it installed, and that the Python interpreter you are running the script in is able to find the library.

Comment: I have used import scipy and the script ran successfully intimating that scipy works fine

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling each of the libraries and then re-installing scikit-0.15.2 using pip?

Comment: Yes, i did reinstall all the libraries and am still getting the same error when i use sklearn

Answer (score 4):

For windows user try to install numpy+mkl package from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn
and after successful installation restart the python

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. installing scipy solved the problem for me.
Try...

```
#sudo pip install scipy
```

What does it say if you fire up a python prompt and type

```
import scipy
```

also there might be some pointers in this thread [ImportError in importing from sklearn: cannot import name check_build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274696/importerror-in-importing-from-sklearn-cannot-import-name-check-build)