# Import in jupyter notebook fails and command line succeeds

Tags: python, jupyter

The following code imports absolutely fine at the command line:

```
# Modelling Algorithms
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
```

However in Jupyter I get the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-f56620e65a88> in <module>()
      8 
      9 # Modelling Algorithms
---> 10 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
     11 from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
     12 from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

/home/username/.virtualenvs/jupyter/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py in <module>()
     54     # process, as it may not be compiled yet
     55 else:
---> 56     from . import __check_build
     57     from .base import clone
     58     __check_build  # avoid flakes unused variable error

ImportError: cannot import name __check_build
```

The output of `sys.executable` is the same.

I would love to fix this.

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193171/importerror-cannot-import-name-check-build-while-importing-tfidfvectorizer-fr)?  Did you restart your notebook?

Comment: Nicely done. Already has scipy installed; needed to restart notebook. Thanks!