# nltk library import error python

Tags: python, svm

i have some problems on my code that show some error when i run it. i'm using python
so, here's my code

```
import collections
import nltk.classify.util, nltk.metrics
from nltk.classify import SklearnClassifier
import csv
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC, SVC
import random
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import itertools
from nltk.collocations import BigramCollocationFinder
from nltk.metrics import BigramAssocMeasures

posdata = []
with open('positive-data.csv', 'rb') as myfile: 
    reader = csv.reader(myfile, delimiter=',')
    for val in reader:
        posdata.append(val[0])      

negdata = []
with open('negative-data.csv', 'rb') as myfile: 
    reader = csv.reader(myfile, delimiter=',')
    for val in reader:
        negdata.append(val[0])          

def word_split(data):   
    data_new = []
    for word in data:
        word_filter = [i.lower() for i in word.split()]
        data_new.append(word_filter)
    return data_new

def word_split_sentiment(data):
    data_new = []
    for (word, sentiment) in data:
        word_filter = [i.lower() for i in word.split()]
        data_new.append((word_filter, sentiment))
    return data_new

def word_feats(words):  
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

stopset = set(stopwords.words('english')) - set(('over', 'under', 'below', 'more', 'most', 'no', 'not', 'only', 'such', 'few', 'so', 'too', 'very', 'just', 'any', 'once'))

def stopword_filtered_word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words if word not in stopset])

def bigram_word_feats(words, score_fn=BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq, n=200):
    bigram_finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(words)
    bigrams = bigram_finder.nbest(score_fn, n)
    """
    print words
    for ngram in itertools.chain(words, bigrams): 
        if ngram not in stopset: 
            print ngram
    exit()
    """    
    return dict([(ngram, True) for ngram in itertools.chain(words, bigrams)])

def bigram_word_feats_stopwords(words, score_fn=BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq, n=200):
    bigram_finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(words)
    bigrams = bigram_finder.nbest(score_fn, n)
    """
    print words
    for ngram in itertools.chain(words, bigrams): 
        if ngram not in stopset: 
            print ngram
    exit()
    """    
    return dict([(ngram, True) for ngram in itertools.chain(words, bigrams) if ngram not in stopset])

# Calculating Precision, Recall & F-measure
def evaluate_classifier(featx):

    negfeats = [(featx(f), 'neg') for f in word_split(negdata)]
    posfeats = [(featx(f), 'pos') for f in word_split(posdata)]

    negcutoff = len(negfeats)*3/4
    poscutoff = len(posfeats)*3/4

    trainfeats = negfeats[:negcutoff] + posfeats[:poscutoff]
    testfeats = negfeats[negcutoff:] + posfeats[poscutoff:]

    classifier = 'svm'  

    for cl in classifier:
        if cl == 'svm':
            classifierName = 'SVM'
            classifier = SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC(), sparse=False)
            classifier.train(trainfeats)

        refsets = collections.defaultdict(set)
        testsets = collections.defaultdict(set)

        for i, (feats, label) in enumerate(testfeats):
                refsets[label].add(i)
                observed = classifier.classify(feats)
                testsets[observed].add(i)

        accuracy = nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testfeats)
        pos_precision = nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
        pos_recall = nltk.metrics.recall(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
        pos_fmeasure = nltk.metrics.f_measure(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
        neg_precision = nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])
        neg_recall = nltk.metrics.recall(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])
        neg_fmeasure =  nltk.metrics.f_measure(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])

        print ''
        print '---------------------------------------'
        print 'SINGLE FOLD RESULT ' + '(' + classifierName + ')'
        print '---------------------------------------'
        print 'accuracy:', accuracy
        print 'precision', (pos_precision + neg_precision) / 2
        print 'recall', (pos_recall + neg_recall) / 2
        print 'f-measure', (pos_fmeasure + neg_fmeasure) / 2    


    print ''

    ## CROSS VALIDATION

    trainfeats = negfeats + posfeats    

    # SHUFFLE TRAIN SET

    random.shuffle(trainfeats)  
    n = 5

    for cl in classifier_list:

        subset_size = len(trainfeats) / n
        accuracy = []
        pos_precision = []
        pos_recall = []
        neg_precision = []
        neg_recall = []
        pos_fmeasure = []
        neg_fmeasure = []
        cv_count = 1
        for i in range(n):      
            testing_this_round = trainfeats[i*subset_size:][:subset_size]
            training_this_round = trainfeats[:i*subset_size] + trainfeats[(i+1)*subset_size:]

            if cl == 'svm':
                classifierName = 'SVM'
                classifier = SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC(), sparse=False)
                classifier.train(training_this_round)

            refsets = collections.defaultdict(set)
            testsets = collections.defaultdict(set)
            for i, (feats, label) in enumerate(testing_this_round):
                refsets[label].add(i)
                observed = classifier.classify(feats)
                testsets[observed].add(i)

            cv_accuracy = nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testing_this_round)
            cv_pos_precision = nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
            cv_pos_recall = nltk.metrics.recall(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
            cv_pos_fmeasure = nltk.metrics.f_measure(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
            cv_neg_precision = nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])
            cv_neg_recall = nltk.metrics.recall(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])
            cv_neg_fmeasure =  nltk.metrics.f_measure(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])

            accuracy.append(cv_accuracy)
            pos_precision.append(cv_pos_precision)
            pos_recall.append(cv_pos_recall)
            neg_precision.append(cv_neg_precision)
            neg_recall.append(cv_neg_recall)
            pos_fmeasure.append(cv_pos_fmeasure)
            neg_fmeasure.append(cv_neg_fmeasure)

            cv_count += 1

        print '---------------------------------------'
        print 'N-FOLD CROSS VALIDATION RESULT ' + '(' + classifierName + ')'
        print '---------------------------------------'
        print 'accuracy:', sum(accuracy) / n
        print 'precision', (sum(pos_precision)/n + sum(neg_precision)/n) / 2
        print 'recall', (sum(pos_recall)/n + sum(neg_recall)/n) / 2
        print 'f-measure', (sum(pos_fmeasure)/n + sum(neg_fmeasure)/n) / 2
        print ''


evaluate_classifier(word_feats)`
```

its suppose to analysis sentiment from csv document using SVM, but when i run the code i got this error [anyone have an idea to fix it??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjceA.png)

really need your help guys

Comment: Install [`SciPy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy) also.

Comment: @JRodDynamite i did but it's still not working

Comment: Have you tried running your script after installing [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)? Maybe it's worth a try. It comes with a plethora of useful packages and is pretty easy to manage.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn and this thread (if you haven't seen this already) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274696/importerror-in-importing-from-sklearn-cannot-import-name-check-build

Comment: Btw does `import numpy` execute correctly?

Comment: @JRodDynamite i tried to running th code again, but the import numpy show some error message

Comment: What is the stacktrace? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37021409/edit) and add it in the question.