# Unable to locate KMeans from sklearn python

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I've installed sklearn using `pip install -U scikit-learn` command and its successfully installed at `c:\python27\lib\site-packages` but when i'm importing `from sklearn.cluster import KMeans` it gives me error. 
[image: Error Detail]. I've checked the package `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn` and its there. How can I get rid of this.

[image: numpy,scipy,sys]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError in importing from sklearn: cannot import name check\_build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274696/importerror-in-importing-from-sklearn-cannot-import-name-check-build)

Comment: scipy is already installed in my case , other packages are installed .

Comment: It does not seem so. Do some test-import of numpy and scipy! (No offense, but a lot of people here do not seem to be able to detect if some install was successful or not!)

Comment: Yes I did . but are installed and I can import them successfully

Comment: Work through [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8461) and [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8461)

Comment: It seems something is wrong with the package. I've tried all methods mentioned in your answers apart from changing inside directory  but it still stuck there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now with your screenshot given, here is the problem:

- [sklearn expects scipy >= 0.13.3](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#installing-the-latest-release)
- yours is **0.12.0**

  - which is **heavily outdated!** (current release: 0.19.1)

Now i see you are on windows and installing scipy there is hard. But please: take your time to search here on SO, as this is asked every day and the answer is still the same. Read the official docs and take a decision on which route to go (not pip install scipy!).

Comment: yes I'm trying to update scipy but getting error. after updating I hope I'll fix it. thanks

Comment: I told you. Do not use pip for updating scipy (on windows). I highly recommend anaconda, but Gohlke's binaries will do too. Read their install-docs. But as far as this question goes: it's answered.