# ImportError: cannot import name __check_build

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

> from sklearn import svm
>
> ImportError: cannot import name __check_build

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError in importing from sklearn: cannot import name check_build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15274696/5085211).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError in importing from sklearn: cannot import name check\_build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274696/importerror-in-importing-from-sklearn-cannot-import-name-check-build)

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to install `scikit-learn` on a fresh virtualenv here but it seems you need to do some extra job to get it up-and-running:

By doing just `pip install scikit-learn` and then `from sklearn import svm` you'll get import errors, it seems the library requires numpy and scipy. So you need to do:

- `pip install numpy scipy`

After that it should work fine.