# Python 2.7 cannot import sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I installed `sklearn`, version: 0.19.2, but cannot import it.

Please see the errors below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-b7c74cbf5af0> in <module>()
----> 1 import sklearn

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>()
    131     # process, as it may not be compiled yet
    132 else:
--> 133     from . import __check_build
    134     from .base import clone
    135     __check_build  # avoid flakes unused variable error

ImportError: cannot import name __check_build
```

Comment: Could you provide a few details about how you installed it (`pip`/`conda`/from source), and what your python version is? (`>>python --version`)

Comment: @DanielLenz    pip install -U scikit-learn

Comment: Might be missing a dependency [`SciPy`](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/index.html#). Try `pip install scipy` then re-run your module. Reference: [ImportError in importing from sklearn: cannot import name check_build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274696/importerror-in-importing-from-sklearn-cannot-import-name-check-build)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError in importing from sklearn: cannot import name check\_build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274696/importerror-in-importing-from-sklearn-cannot-import-name-check-build)

Comment: None of the solutions worked for me. I keep getting the error:

Comment: As below: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 135
    __check_build  # avoid flakes unused variable error
                                                      ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level