# ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'

Tags: scikit-learn

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build\__init__.py in <module>()

     43 try:
---> 44     from ._check_build import check_build  # noqa
     45 except ImportError as e:
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f14d678f34eb> in <module>()



      1 from keras.models import Sequential
      2 from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
----> 3 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      4 import numpy
      5 import pandas as pd

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>()
     61     # process, as it may not be compiled yet
     62 else:
---> 63     from . import __check_build
     64     from .base import clone
     65     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build\__init__.py in <module>()
     44     from ._check_build import check_build  # noqa
     45 except ImportError as e:
---> 46     raise_build_error(e)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build\__init__.py in raise_build_error(e)
     39 to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
     40 `make` in the source directory.
---> 41 %s""" % (e, local_dir, ''.join(dir_content).strip(), msg))
     42 
     43 try:
```

> ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'
>
> ---

```
Contents of C:\Users\owaisaaa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build:
setup.py                  _check_build.cp36-win32.pyd__init__.py
__pycache__
```

---

It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.

I recently used the pycharm on the same machine and downloaded the packages in it. From that moment onward I am getting the above mentioned error in my jupyter notebook.

Comment: Hi, I'm also getting same error did you fix it? If so, please post your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try installing scipy and restarting python shell

Comment: got similar query posted try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274696/importerror-in-importing-from-sklearn-cannot-import-name-check-build

Comment: I had a python folder installed outside the Anaconda3 folder. I think there was a clash between libraries. I deleted that folder and this worked for me. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading scikit-learn worked for me:

`$ pip install --upgrade scikit-learn`