# ImportError with Scikit-learn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have installed scikit-learn on my windows machine using pip and when the installation was done I tried to import it and use it in a jupyter notebook, However I'm getting the below import error.

> ImportError: cannot import name '_IS_32BIT'

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Just to confirm...do you have numpy and scipy installed too?

Comment: Yes I do. numpy 1.17.2, scipy 1.3.1, and scikit-learn 0.21.3

Comment: @Mow1993 Try after restarting the kernel in jupyter notebook.

Comment: I tried, unfortunately I'm getting the same error.

Comment: this is similiar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274696/importerror-in-importing-from-sklearn-cannot-import-name-check-build

Comment: I tried this, didn't work. However I just tried uninstalling scikit-learn and installing it again and it worked :)