# ImportError: Cannot import name check_build from partially initialize module 'sklearn'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

I'm getting the following error while trying to import from sklearn

```
from pandas import read_csv
from numpy import mean
from matplotlib import pyplot
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
```

**Here is the error:**

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c57768f466c0> in <module>
      2 from numpy import mean
      3 from matplotlib import pyplot
----> 4 from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
     79     # it and importing it first would fail if the OpenMP dll cannot be found.
     80     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
---> 81     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
     82     from .base import clone
     83     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions

ImportError: cannot import name '__check_build' from partially initialized module 'sklearn' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError in importing from sklearn: cannot import name check\_build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274696/importerror-in-importing-from-sklearn-cannot-import-name-check-build)

Comment: In any case, `from numpy import mean` is a terrible idea. Use `import numpy as np` and `np.mean()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, but i managed to solve it..Worth your time to try:
Please follow the sequence.
in CMD,

1. - a) pip uninstall numpy
   - b) pip uninstall scipy
   - c) pip uninstall matplotlib
   - d) pip uninstall sklearn
   - e) pip uninstall scikit-learn

Then,

2. - a) pip install numpy
   - b) pip install scipy
   - c) pip install matplotlib
   - d) pip install sklearn
   - e) pip install scikit-learn

Follow 1a) to 1e) , then 2a) to 2e).