# cannot import name '__check_build' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I do my first ML programming and get into trouble in first step in importing that is an error:

```
cannot import name '__check_build' from partially initialized module 'sklearn' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\bahramhh\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py)
```

I have read all of the answers in this questions and done all of suggestions:
[ImportError in importing from sklearn: cannot import name check_build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274696/importerror-in-importing-from-sklearn-cannot-import-name-check-build)
also I have created venv either in windows cmd and anaconda it didn't works :|

Comment: It would help to share the code you are getting an error on.