# Installed scikit-learn doesn't work properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip, sklearn-pandas

I am getting this error when I run the following code:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation
```

> ImportError: cannot import name '__check_build' from partially initialized module 'sklearn' (most likely due to a circular import).

When I check `pip freeze` scikit-learn is installed.
Also,I tried to uninstall and reinstall sklearn,now I am getting a different error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\<user>\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\sklearn\\datasets\\tests\\data\\openml\\292\\api-v1-json-data-list-data_name-australian-limit-2-data_version-1-status-deactivated.json.gz'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError in importing from sklearn: cannot import name check\_build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274696/importerror-in-importing-from-sklearn-cannot-import-name-check-build)

Comment: @SamMason already tried all of them.Doesn't work still

Comment: Use `virtualenv` or `conda` env and then install `sklearn`

Comment: @bigbounty I am installing using env already

Comment: does windows still have a 255 char path limit?  might be worth trying to install using something that involves shorter paths if that's the case

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html

> It can happen that pip fails to install packages when reaching the default path size limit of Windows if Python is installed in a nested location such as the AppData folder structure under the user home directory, for instance:

```
C:\Users\username>C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe -m pip install scikit-learn
Collecting scikit-learn
...
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python37\\site-packages\\sklearn\\datasets\\tests\\data\\openml\\292\\api-v1-json-data-list-data_name-australian-limit-2-data_version-1-status-deactivated.json.gz
```

> In this case it is possible to lift that limit in the Windows registry by using the regedit tool:

1. Type “regedit” in the Windows start menu to launch regedit.
2. Go to the `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` key.
3. Edit the value of the LongPathsEnabled property of that key and set it to 1.
4. Reinstall scikit-learn (ignoring the previous broken installation):

`pip install --exists-action=i scikit-learn`

Comment: changed it to 1 and run the pip command as mentioned.It worked after restarting the shell